# creating contents file for each tar file in a directory using a script

Tags: linux

Currently I have have over 70 tar files in a directory. To save the contents of each of these files, I run the command tar -tvf file1.tar > file1_contents.txt

I am looking to see how this can be done for over 50 files in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses bash (or any other POSIX shell); this is an assumption on my part as you did not tag a specific language. Switch to the directory in question, then:

```
for i in *.tar; do
  tar tvf "$i" > "${i%.tar*}_contents.txt"
done
```

You should really learn about loops in your preferred scripting language; they are very powerful. As a side note, with some `tar` implementations like `bsdtar` or recent versions of GNU `tar`, this will also work on compressed tar files (`tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` for example); you'll just need to change the `*.tar` to reflect the other files.

Comment: I want to thank you. I am responding late, but i just want to tell you this worked for me and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're quite welcome. If you get a chance, could you accept my answer?